# camera size X=Y on mac osX

Tags: camera, osx, resolution

When I resizing the resolution size of the camera, I get the same on both axes.
X and Y change the Y size…

osx 10.13.6
blender 2019 02 15

Comment: I can't replicated this behaviour. If you think it's a bug, file a bug report.

Comment: Also, 2.8 is beta, update to the latest and test if the problem persist before filing a bug report.